# How to get rid of truncate warnings when initializing a parameter-sized array?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, quartus

I am aware that I can use `'1`, `'b1100`, `'d12`, ... ,  to create arrays with sizes based on context, and if I initialize the array with a constant, there are no warnings. For example

```
wire[DEPTH-1:0] read_addr_next = 'd1;
```

However, if I write instead

```
wire[DEPTH-1:0] read_addr_next = read_addr + 'd1;
```

Triggers the following warning on quartus

```
Warning (10230): Verilog HDL assignment warning at fifo_controller.sv(9): truncated value with size 32 to match size of target (4)
```

Is there a straightforward way to fix the warning without creating a new constant or resorting to `{DEPTH-1{0},1'b1}`?

Something like

```
wire[DEPTH-1:0] read_addr_next = read_addr + DEPTH'd1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In System Verilog `'d1` is a 32-bit constant. So, the message is reasonable. Should quartus print it or not in this case is another question. Other compilers are silent here.

Your concat example is a good one and it is a usual way to handle this kind of issues. However, in this case you should be able to use a single-bit constant: `read_addr_next = read_addr + 1'd1;`. I hope it will make the message go away.

Another way is utilizing text macros:

```
`define DEPTH 4
...
read_addr_next = read_addr + `DEPTH'd1;
```

In SystemVerilog you can use typedefs to handle it, but it is not the best way either and I do not know if quartus will be silent in this case or not.

```
  typedef logic [DEPTH-1:0] dtype;
  wire[DEPTH-1:0] read_addr_next = read_addr + dtype'('d1);
```

And finally, there might be a way in quartus to turn off this message.

Answer (score 0):

In System Verilog you can directly cast to the size you want.

```
read_addr_next = read_addr + DEPTH'(1);
```

But, since you're only incrementing, it's also fairly common to simply add a single bit, and is a little more straightforward. The leading zeroes will be added on by the tool.

```
read_addr_next = read_addr + 1'b1;
```

The direct cast is more useful for other situations, like resolving the size of a streaming operator when it is being used as an operand.

```
example_tmp  = VEC_SIZE'({<<{1'b0,op_vec_a[VEC_SIZE-2:0]}}) ^ 2**op_int_b;
```

Without the explicit cast size, some tools will throw an error because the resultant size of the streaming operator is not clear. Point being, you can use it in other places to resolve size mismatches.